# Signature Pad does not follow cursor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, signaturepad

I am using [angular2-signaturepad](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-signaturepad) library to work with signature in my angular project. Here is my code:

**signature.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SignaturePage } from './signature';
import { SignaturePadModule } from 'angular2-signaturepad';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AssinarPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(AssinarPage),
    SignaturePadModule
  ],
})
export class SignaturePageModule {}
```

**signature.ts**

```
export class SignaturePage {
  @ViewChild(SignaturePad) private signaturePad : SignaturePad;
   signaturePadOptions = {
      minWidth: 0.4,
      maxWidth: 1.5,
      dotSize: 1.5,
      penColor: "DarkBlue",
      /* INVERSE BECAUSE IT IS SHOW ONLY IN LANDSCAPE */
      canvasWidth: platform.height(),
      canvasHeight: platform.width() + 30
    }

    drawComplete () {
    if (this.signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
      return this.alertService.showError('Sign first.');
    }

    this.signatureImage = this.signaturePad.toDataURL();
  }

  drawClear () {
    this.signaturePad.clear();
  }
```

**signature.html**

```
<signature-pad [options]="signaturePadOptions" id="signatureCanvas" drag-content="false" ></signature-pad>
```

I saw the live demo of this library in this [link](http://lathonez.com/angular2-signaturepad-demo/) and it is working perfectly here. But in my project, **signature is not following the cursor**.

Is there any configuration i need to change, so the signature follows the cursor in the signature pad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to resize the canvas and after that, signature followed the cursor in the signature pad.

```
  canvasResize() {
    let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    this.signaturePad.set('minWidth', 1);
    this.signaturePad.set('canvasWidth', canvas.offsetWidth);
    this.signaturePad.set('canvasHeight', canvas.offsetHeight);
  }
```

Comment: I saw this canvasResize() function as a solution elsewhere (also by you, @setu Basak) but you haven't explained how or where you invoke this function. Can you shed some light please? Thanks.

Comment: Apologies. I didn't explore long enough. the place to invoke it was in my ngAfterViewInit() as I'm working in Angular 5. Works like a charm. Well done @Setu Basak

Comment: Although, setting the minWidth in the canvasResize was overkill as it is already suggested to set it in signaturePadOptions object and ngAfterViewInit(). See https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-signaturepad

Answer (score 0):

//Responsive signature pad removes signature if drawn again on the same canvas. Below are the lines added to tackle that

```
const data = signaturePad.toData();  // saves the previously drawn canvas to local    variable

// lines below makes the cursor responsive to all screen sizes
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
signaturePad.set('minWidth', 1);
signaturePad.set('canvasWidth', canvas.offsetWidth);
signaturePad.set('canvasHeight', canvas.offsetHeight);

signaturePad.fromData(data,{ clear: false });  // disallows the clearing of the canvas while drawing something again on the same canvas
```