# Signature Pad Break on rotation

Tags: css, angular, signaturepad

I have same issue reference to https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad/issues/76

I have an app which is locked in portrait mode but my signature screen should rotate in landscape as design specs suggests. I rotated the screen in landscape using CSS which works fine but when I try to write a signature, the drawing begins either off screen or opposite of the input and in some instance it draws in the opposite direction.

CSS which I used is

```
transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: left top;
    width: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
```

I used the solution of github issue mentioned in question but no help, I tried [Signature Pad does not follow cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48782913/4587973) this solution also but did not work for me.

You can observe the behaviour of cursor and signature getting written on [here](http://tso2016stage.wpengine.com/s/mf-video/19-09-27-12-05-47.mp4)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find solution ?

Comment: @PankajWanjari yes, did it with css